# Print fails (expand_more.xml)

Tags: android, printing

So I've got a problem when trying to print from my android application. The codes works perfectly on my Samsung Note 5, but when I move it to a Pine64 running Android 6.01 it crashes with (exception shortened for brevity):

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #108: Binary XML file line #272: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_expand_more.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020003
```

I've even downloaded and manually included the ic_expand_more.xml (assuming it would override) but still no luck. I'm also confused by the id given in th error, because if I look in the generated R.java the id links to:

```
public static final int actionBarSize=0x7f020003;
```

Shouldn't it link to a drawable or a view? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Here's my print code:

```
 PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
 String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
 printManager.print(jobName, new ZoneEventPrintAdapter(ReportsActivity.this, mAdapter.getDataSource()), null);
```

ZoneEventPrintAdapter is just a PrintDocumentAdapter but it's crashing before I even get to onLayout.

Has anyone seen this before?

**EDIT**

It seems to be the print dialog that's causing the crash. I've looked at the layout at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a798c0a/packages/PrintSpooler/res/layout/print_activity.xml?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F

which is where the ic_expand_more image button is situated. My phone is running Android 7.0 and the device is running 6.0.1 so I imagine the ic_expand_more.xml resource is missing from the devices resources. Does that sound right?

Comment: I think this is device specific because other OS 6 devices work fine. I think you should report this to the device manufacturer

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually ended up downgrading to Android 5 and it works just fine. I still don't know why the issue occurred to begin with, but for now, I have a solution.